# How to join single array into multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, join

So lets say, i have First Array with values like this

**First Array** :

```
$first : [Array
(
    [0] => CreationDate
    [1] => OrderNumber
    [2] => OrderDate
    [3] => InvoiceNumber
)
```

and **Second Array** with value like this : 
$Second : [Array

```
(
    [0] => 2011-08-09
    [1] => 123123
    [2] => 2011-08-09
    [3] => XXAXXA
)
```

what i want is to get output like this :

```
$Join : [Array
(
    [CreationDate] => 2011-08-09
    [OrderNumber] => 123123
    [OrderDate] => 2011-08-09
    [InvoiceNumber] => XXAXXA

)
```

***noted**, i already using this nested foreach to get the result

```
$join = array();

    foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($values as $key2) {      
        $join[][$value] = $key2;
    }

}
```

but it return Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 29364224 bytes)

so if u guys have more efficient method, i open my mind to know it
Thanks u guys

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and use the first array for the keys and the second array for the values:

```
$a = [
    0 => "CreationDate",
    1 => "OrderNumber",
    2 => "OrderDate",
    3 => "InvoiceNumber"
];
$b = [
    0 => "2011-08-09",
    1 => "123123",
    2 => "2011-08-09",
    3 => "XXAXXA"

];

print_r(array_combine($a, $b));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [CreationDate] => 2011-08-09
    [OrderNumber] => 123123
    [OrderDate] => 2011-08-09
    [InvoiceNumber] => XXAXXA
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/If5JU)

Comment: yess, it worked, but i have 672 lines in $First and $Second Array, both of them is 672 lines, when i use combine it stuck, it only combine 22 lines, 
any suggesttion ?

Comment: So after 22 lines you get the Fatal error? Dit you try to increase the memory a bit? Perhaps there is some very inefficient looping?

Comment: @hope9 We can only work with the details you give in your question. If your actual array is different, you need to update the question with this details. Are all 672 items in the first array unique?

Answer (score 0):

```
$join = array();

foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    $join[$value] = $values[$key];
}
```

which `$names` and `$values` are your arrays.

## Edit:

Since you run out of memory, I would recommend you to unset the original array.

```
$join = array();

foreach ($First as $key => $value) {
    $join[$value] = $Second[$key];
    unset($First[$key]);
    unset($Second[$key]);
}
```

and use `array_keys($join)` to get the first array and `array_values($join)` to get the second array.

Comment: it work, but only few lines, actually i got 672 line in $First array and $Second array